# MongoDB c# driver - Connect via proxy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

There is a Windows Forms application, which uses MongoDB driver. 
I would like the MongoDB driver to make all its connection via a specified proxy.

Should there be a way to modify app.config to achieve it?
Can I define it in the driver itself?

Comment: Are you talking about a HTTP proxy? The driver connects to the database over TCP: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Driver/Internal/MongoConnection.cs so I'm pretty sure you won't be able to use a HTTP proxy.

Comment: @MartinOwen, the link got broken, but I believe this one works: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Connections/BinaryConnection.cs

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the MongoDB docs on connection strings: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Connectionstrings

How your particular application stores this connection string isn't defined by MongoDB.  It doesn't use app.config unless your code uses it.

Comment: Not within MongoDB / the application, no.  What kind of proxy are you talking about?